# How to use Flutter BLoC pattern on specific scenarios?

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc, rxdart

Recently I am start to learn Flutter and its BLoC partten, and there are many class in BLoC library, like `Bloc`, `PublishSubject`, `StreamController`, `BehaviorSubject` and etc..

My question is, what the scenarios that I can use these classes? For example, I can inherited from `bloc` or not inherited from it, but why? I am confuse for that, What's the usage scenarios for those classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see, there are more than one ways to implement Bloc in your apps. The class you mentioned above are in fact from different packages: `PublishSubject` and `BehaviorSubject` are from [rxdart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) package while `StreamController` is within the Flutter SDK package [dart:async](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart)

However, you are not required to use all or even any of them to implement Bloc in your Flutter apps. I'll make an example by implement Bloc without using any package:

**1. Implement Bloc the vanilla way:**
You can implement Bloc using what's in Flutter SDK without using other package. Usually you create a bloc class separating your logic from the UI. The class might look like this:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

// This is the class that handle all the logic such as receiving data from API, process those data, etc (I'll call it a data processing unit)
class YourBloc {
  
  // Create a stream to send processed data to the UI
  final StreamController _someController = StreamController();

  Stream get someStream => _someController.stream;

  // Get the data from API, then send the data to stream here. Usually an async function
  void loadData() async {
    final data = await doYourApiCall(); // Get data from API
    var processedData = processYourData(data);
    _someController.add(processedData);
  }

  dispose() {
    _someController.close();
  }
}
```

Meanwhile in the UI, you initiate the loadData() and listen to the response data with `StreamBuilder`:

```dart
class _SomeScreenState extends State<SomeScreen> {
  // Initiate your bloc
  final YourBloc _bloc = YourBloc();

  // Make the loadData() call
  @override
  void initState() {
    _bloc.loadData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder( // Listen to the datastream with StreamBuilder
      stream: _bloc.someStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData)
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => _buildYourItem(index),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**2. So what's the packages are for**
There are some packages you can make use of to implement Bloc such as [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) or [rxdart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart). `flutter_bloc` provides a way to structure your bloc consistenly using Bloc/Event/State concepts, `rx_dart` provides many tools so you can manipulate the `Stream` to your own need. You might see people mentioned [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) as well, it's main purpose is to pass an object down the widget tree and create a data flow through out your app.

Each is already pretty mature and implemented by many programmers. I recommend going into the documentations of each one of them only *after* you implement Bloc the vanilla way so you can actually understand what they're doing behind the scenes.